# Blazor WebAssembly + Google auth + authenticate API requests

Tags: authentication, google-oauth, blazor-webassembly

My scenario:

1. Build a Single Page Application with Blazor WebAssembly (preferably .NET 8).
2. Have users sign in with their Google accounts. (Just any Google account, only need a unique user ID and nothing else.)
3. Implement a .NET backend and use the same authentication mechanism and identity also for the backend API calls. So, the Blazor app needs to grab the token from the sign-in and include it in the backend API requests as a bearer token.
4. Some graceful way to handle token expiration. In the sign-in I get an ID token that is valid for 1 hour. I need some reasonably secure way for the backend API requests to keep working, if the user keeps using the Blazor app for longer than 1 hour.

I've been doing a lot of googling and prototyping around the topic, but I haven't been able to figure out a combination that works.

I would prefer to use available libraries as much as possible and minimize the amount of my own code for doing a working auth.

Any suggestions?

Examples of problems I have faced:

- The Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication library doesn't provide an interface to access the ID token, so that I could grab the actual token and include it in the API requests. (It only provides access to the claims etc. but not the token itself.)
- I could hack around the previous problem by parsing the ID token from the login callback URL, but that doesn't give me any way to refresh the token in the background.
- One option would be to get an auth code from the response, pass that to the backend, make the backend exchange that to a refresh token, and then have an API endpoint in the backend for refreshing the ID token. However, I would need to be able to get the auth code for this purpose.
- When I try to include "code" as part of the "response_type" for the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication library, it gives an error saying that a hybrid authentication flow is not supported, and doesn't do the sign-in at all.
- I have also played around with the "Sign in with Google" HTML and JavaScript APIs. However, I can't figure out how to either get the auth code in the response (to be exchanged to a refresh token in the backend) or make it so that a JavaScript callback would be automatically called also on repeat visits to the application, or when the id token expires.

Some options that I think I will consider next:

- Doing some kind of custom implementation on the Blazor app for interfacing with the Google sign-in endpoint and have full control over the OAuth request that goes in. Request both ID token and code, then pass the code to the server-side etc.
- Use the ID token received from Google only for initial authentication, then in the server-side cook up my own mechanism for creating some bearer token and refreshing them.

However, both of the above ideas sound like there is way too much work, code and possibility for errors in them. I would really prefer something more ready-made and known-to-work.

Comment: Look at Microsoft Entra - what used to be Azure AD B2C.